# How to get the total from 2 column in a week

Tags: mysql, loops, date, stored-procedures, time

How can I get the Total Undertime for each employee per week. per month. I have a `view` in which it has columns `undertime` and `overtime` per day per employee. however i need to get the `TotalUndertime` per week.

```
|EmpID  |DayofWeek|DatePresent|Overtime |Undertime|
|3050001|Friday   |2016-04-01 |         |00:01:00 |
|3050001|Monday   |2016-04-04 |         |01:00:00 |
|3050001|Tuesday  |2016-04-05 |00:30:00 |         |
|3050001|Wednesday|2016-04-06 |00:30:00 |         |
|3050001|Thursday |2016-04-07 |00:05:00 |         |
|3050001|Friday   |2016-04-08 |00:05:00 |         |
```

If the employee has an `Undertime` on `Monday`, the employee can pay for the `Undertime` on the following days from `Tuesday - Friday`. Or if the Employee has an `Undertime` on `Tuesday`, the employee has `Wednesday - Friday` to pay for the `Undertime. The`TotalUndertime = "00:01:00"` in the table shown above.

I'm just a newbie when it comes to mysql queries using date and time. Should i use function or procedure?

I used this code to get it but it didn't work.

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE  `getUndertime` ( IN  `varDatePresent` DATE, IN  `varEmpID` VARCHAR( 8 ) ) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN SELECT DAY( LAST_DAY( varDatePresent ) ) 
INTO @totaldays ;

SET @daycount =0;

WHILE(
@daycount < @totaldays
) DO SELECT Undertime
FROM view_dtr
WHERE EmpID LIKE  '%varEmpID%'
AND DatePresent = varDatePresent
INTO @undertime ;

SELECT Overtime
FROM view_dtr
WHERE EmpID LIKE  '%varEmpID%'
AND DATE_ADD( DatePresent, INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
INTO @overtime ;

SET @totalUndertime = @undertime - @overtime ;

SET @daycount = @daycount +1;

END WHILE;

SELECT @totalUndertime ;

END ;
```

Any suggestion will help me very much.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't `Group By` do the trick?

```
SELECT EMPID, Week(DatePresent) as 'WeekNumber',
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(COALESCE(undertime,0)-COALESCE(overtime,0)) * 3600) as 'TotalUndertime' 
FROM table_name GROUP BY EmpID, Week(DatePresent)
```

Usage: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Edit: Based on your definition of `TotalUndertime`. As a side note, I strongly suggest not to use `LIKE` when filtering your `EMPID`.

Comment: I've done it before but without the COALESCE() function. It helped a lot although the results were whole numbers, which means it's computing the hours, e.g. -12, 4, etc. i need to find a way to get the minutes as well.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice the datatype for your undertime and overtime column. Let me test that via sqlfiddle and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Added SEC_TO_TIME function.

Comment: btw, can you please specify your table structure? I'm not sure if your using timestamp or datetime for `undertime` and `overtime`.

Comment: If your datatype is timestamp, then you can simply do `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, undertime,overtime))) as 'TotalUndertime' ` instead.

Comment: Don't laugh or judge but i'm using `VARCHAR` for `Overtime`, `Login-Logout`, `Undertime` and `TotalWork`. I used this query to compute for each of them `SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( STR_TO_DATE(  Logout ,  '%r' ) ) - TIME_TO_SEC( STR_TO_DATE( Login ,  '%r' ) ) -3600 ) ) AS TotalWork`

Comment: Why don't you just redesign your table and change it to `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`? Is there a specific reason as to why you are using `VARCHAR`? I assume that what you are trying to create is not used in production yet, am I correct?

Comment: yes. I used `VARCHAR` because first, i'm not familiar in using `date` and `timestamp`, and second, our attendance system was made by another person and it gives an output  in `textfile` format. I used `LOAD INFILE` however the `Logout` appeared in a different format I tried looking for solutions but gave up and since then i used `VARCHAR` i'll leave you a message after i redesign my tables. Thank you for the effort of teaching me, a newbie.

Comment: You are very much welcome. I understand why you used `VARCHAR`, but as you can see, a temporary solution before has now become a bane. Changing the datatype now would be greatly advised as more trivial issues like this would surely be encountered in the days to come.

Comment: I used this and it worked `SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( COALESCE( TIME_TO_SEC( undertime ) , 0 ) - COALESCE( TIME_TO_SEC( overtime ) , 0 ) ) ) ` Thanks a bunch for teaching me.

Comment: Glad I could help you. BTW, does `TIME_TO_SEC` return `NULL` if `undertime` is `NULL`? I'm not sure atm, because if it returns `0` whenever `undertime` is `NULL` or not, then I believe `COALESCE` is no longer necessary.